# Trying to save values from tkInter scale

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first post so please have patience

I've got a school assignment to create an art supplies application and I've drawn a blank why my tkinter scale values are not saving to a file.

The customer details and submit button code works as expected (saves to a file = info.txt)
The Order tab page doesn't work as expected = does not append info.txt with specific quantities of art supplies ordered

Here's my code

```
#def mainmenu():
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import re
NON_ALPHA_RE = re.compile('[^A-Z0-9]+')
POSTCODE_RE = re.compile('^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]? [0-9][A-Z]{2}$')

def normalise_postcode(eZIP_Postalcode):
    eZIP_Postalcode = NON_ALPHA_RE.sub('', eZIP_Postalcode.upper())
    eZIP_Postalcode = eZIP_Postalcode[:-3] + ' ' + eZIP_Postalcode[-3:]
    if POSTCODE_RE.match(eZIP_Postalcode):
        return eZIP_Postalcode
    return None


def submit() :
    invalidtext_1.set("")
    invalidtext_2.set("")
    invalidtext_3.set("")
    invalidtext_4.set("")
    invalidtext_5.set("")
    eName  =Name.get()
    eSurname =Surname.get()    
    ecountry =country.get()
    ecity =city.get()
    eAddressLine1 = AddressLine1.get()
    eAddressLine2 = AddressLine2.get()
    eState_Province_Region = State_Province_Region.get()
    eZIP_Postalcode = ZIP_Postalcode.get()
    valid = True

    if eName.isalpha() == False:
        invalidtext_1.set("Invalid forename. Please use letters only.")
        valid = False
    if eSurname.isalpha() == False:
        invalidtext_2.set("Invalid surname. Please use letters only.")
        valid = False
    if ecountry.isalpha() == False:
        invalidtext_3.set("Invalid country name. Please use letters only.")
        valid = False
    if ecity.isalpha() == False:
        invalidtext_4.set("Invalid city name. Please use letters only.")
        valid = False
    if eZIP_Postalcode != normalise_postcode(eZIP_Postalcode):
        invalidtext_5.set("Please enter a valid postcode.")
        valid = False
    if valid == False:

        return
    else:

        eName = eName.ljust(150)
        eSurname = eSurname.ljust(150)
        ecountry = ecountry.ljust(150)
        ecity = ecity.ljust(150)
        eAddressLine1 = eAddressLine1.ljust(150)
        eAddressLine2 = eAddressLine2.ljust(150)
        eState_Province_Region = eState_Province_Region.ljust(150)
        eZIP_Postalcode = eZIP_Postalcode.ljust(150)
        fileObject = open("Info.txt","a")

        fileObject.write(eName +"\n" + eSurname +"\n" + ecountry +"\n" + ecity +"\n" + eAddressLine1 +"\n" + eAddressLine2 +"\n" + eState_Province_Region +"\n" + eZIP_Postalcode +"\n")
        fileObject.close()

        return

def submitNumber():
    Paint=Paint.get()
    Paper=Paper.get()
    PaintBrush =PaintBrush.get()
    Easles=Easles.get()
    Pencils=Pencils.get()

    Paint = Paint.ljust(150)
    Paper = Paper.ljust(150)
    PaintBrush = PaintBrush.ljust(150)
    Easles = Easles.ljust(150)
    Pencils = Pencils.ljust(150)

    fileObject = open("Info.txt","a")
    fileObject.write(paint + paper + paintbrush + Easles + pencils +"\n")
    fileObject.close()


def mainWindow():
    global Name, invalidtext_1, frame1, invalidtext_2,Surname,city,country,invalidtext_3,invalidtext_4,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,State_Province_Region,ZIP_Postalcode,invalidtext_5
    window=Tk()


    window.title("Artist Products")
    window.configure(background = "#800000")
    window.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    # DON'T NEED window.geometry("500x300") #Width x Height

    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

    #Tab 1 (as in the number 1!)

    tab_control.add(tab1, text='Customer details')
    Label (tab1, text="Name:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Name=StringVar()
    eName=Entry(tab1, textvariable=Name)
    eName.grid(row=1, column=1)

    invalidtext_1=StringVar()
    invalid_1= Label(tab1, textvariable=invalidtext_1, font="Helvetica 12 ", fg="red")
    invalid_1.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W)

    Label (tab1, text="Surname:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=2, column=0)
    Surname=StringVar()
    eSurname=Entry(tab1, textvariable=Surname)
    eSurname.grid(row=2, column=1)

    invalidtext_2=StringVar()
    invalid_2= Label(tab1, textvariable=invalidtext_2, font="Helvetica 12 ", fg="red")
    invalid_2.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky=W)

    Label (tab1, text="Adress Line 1:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=3, column=0)
    AddressLine1=StringVar()
    eAddressLine1=Entry(tab1, textvariable=AddressLine1)
    eAddressLine1.grid(row=3, column=1)

    Label (tab1, text="Adress Line 2:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=4, column=0)
    AddressLine2=StringVar()
    eAddressLine2=Entry(tab1, textvariable=AddressLine2)
    eAddressLine2.grid(row=4, column=1)

    Label (tab1, text="State/province/region:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=5, column=0)
    State_Province_Region=StringVar()
    eState_Province_Region=Entry(tab1, textvariable=State_Province_Region)
    eState_Province_Region.grid(row=5, column=1)

    Label (tab1, text="ZIP/postal code:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=6, column=0)
    ZIP_Postalcode=StringVar()
    eZIP_Postalcode=Entry(tab1, textvariable=ZIP_Postalcode)
    eZIP_Postalcode.grid(row=6, column=1)

    invalidtext_5=StringVar()
    invalid_5= Label(tab1, textvariable=invalidtext_5, font="Helvetica 12 ", fg="red")
    invalid_5.grid(row=6,column=2, sticky=W)

    Label (tab1, text="Country name:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=7, column=0)
    country=StringVar()
    ecountry=Entry(tab1, textvariable=country)
    ecountry.grid(row=7, column=1)

    invalidtext_3=StringVar()
    invalid_3= Label(tab1, textvariable=invalidtext_3, font="Helvetica 12 ", fg="red")
    invalid_3.grid(row=7,column=2, sticky=W)

    Label (tab1, text="City:" , bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=8, column=0)
    city=StringVar()
    ecity=Entry(tab1, textvariable=city)
    ecity.grid(row=8, column=1)

    invalidtext_4=StringVar()
    invalid_4= Label(tab1, textvariable=invalidtext_4, font="Helvetica 12 ", fg="red")
    invalid_4.grid(row=8,column=2, sticky=W)

####Tab 2
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab2, text='View All Products')

    Label (tab2, text='Paper(50 pages non lined):£3',bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Paper = Scale(tab2, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    Paper.grid(row=1, column=1)

    Label (tab2, text='Paint (acrylic):£6' ,bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=2, column=0)
    Paint = Scale(tab2, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    Paint.grid(row=2, column=1)

    Label (tab2, text='Paint brush:£4' ,bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=3, column=0)
    PaintBrush = Scale(tab2, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    PaintBrush.grid(row=3, column=1)

    Label (tab2, text='Easels:£6' ,bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=4, column=0)
    Easels = Scale(tab2, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    Easels.grid(row=4, column=1)

    Label (tab2, text='Pencils:£4.50' ,bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=5, column=0)
    Pencils = Scale(tab2, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    Pencils.grid(row=5, column=1)

    #Tab 3
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab3, text='Invoices')
    tab_control.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #Tab 4
    tab4 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab4, text='Basket')
    tab_control.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Label (tab4, text="Basket",bg="#800", fg="white", font="futuran 12").grid(row=1, column=0)

    #Tab 5
    tab5 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab5, text='Orders')
    tab_control.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #buttons
    b6=Button(tab1, text="Close",command=quit, width=10)
    b6.grid(row=12, column=0)
    b6=Button(tab2, text="Close",command=quit, width=10)
    b6.grid(row=12, column=0)
    b6=Button(tab3, text="Close",command=quit, width=10)
    b6.grid(row=12, column=0)
    b6=Button(tab4, text="Close",command=quit, width=10)
    b6.grid(row=12, column=0)
    b6=Button(tab5, text="Close",command=quit, width=10)
    b6.grid(row=12, column=0)
    b18= Button(tab1, text=" Submit ",command=submit,width=10)
    b18.grid(row=12, column=1)
    b17= Button(tab2, text=" Submit ",command=submit,width=10)
    b17.grid(row=12, column=1)
    frame2 = Frame(window)
    frame2.grid()

    return window

    window = mainWindow()
    window.mainloop()

mainWindow()
```

I've also tried to get the customer details submit button to save to the file and then close down the customer details tab or ar least move the focus to the 'View all products' tab (so that the user can then concentrate on their order).

Help!

Comment: We don't need the whole program. Please try to condense this down to a [mcve]. For example, if the problem is about saving scale values to a file then we don't need much more code than a scale or two, the code you're using to write values to a file, and enough extra code to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Aside from the issue Bryan mentioned, it's a fairly good question. The recommendation for the minimal reproducible example is both for you and the people answering; you are more likely to get help if they don't have to sift through your whole program, and it's easier to find the problem in a simple example. You're also more likely to find the problem yourself in the act of rewriting it (here, you might have noticed the errant capitalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is one of variable names. You are clobbering the scale object with the result of a call to get(), but then you write to what I assume was the variable you intended to assign. That variable is never initialized and is therefore `None`, so nothing is written to the file.
e.g.

```
Paint = Paint.get()
...
Paint = Paint.ljust(150)
...
fileObject.write(... + paint + ...)
```

should be

```
paint = Paint.get()
...
paint = Paint.ljust(150)
...
fileObject.write(... + paint)
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, could you please accept the answer? Thanks :)